# reading Resource file using GetGlobalResourceObject

Tags: c#, sharepoint, resources

I have two projects in vs2010. one sharepoint which deplyes a Resource file (AppGlobalResource).

When I use the following code in the sharepoint project, it runs well:

```
public static string GetResourceString(string messageCode)
        {

                var text = System.Web.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceFiles.Default, messageCode);
                return text.ToString();

        }
```

However if I use the C# code (which is included as reference in the sharepoint project) it does not work

Comment: I get this error:Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.myresourcefile.resx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: Could you add more explanation? I don't understand the difference between the two methods you're using.